# Mergesort doesn't sort my array correctly

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, sorting

I'm trying to sort this array:

```
[5 1 3 2 2 9 1]
```

I've ran the debugger and have been getting strange results. I put a break point on the line

```
merge(left, right);
```

and after the first pass these are the sub-arrays:

```
left = [1 3 5 2 2]
right = [9]
```

so I'm pretty sure the 'divide' part is where I'm going wrong. Can somebody have a look at my code and see if they can spot the error?

```
public int[] arrayToSort = { 5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 9, 1 };
...
private void mergeSort(int[] array, int low, int high) {
    // Base case
    if (!(high - low <= 1)) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        // Split array into sub-arrays
        int[] left = new int[mid];
        int[] right = new int[high - mid];
        // Fill sub-arrays
        for (int i = low; i < mid; i++) {
            left[i - low] = array[i];
        }
        for (int i = mid; i < high; i++) {
            right[i - mid] = array[i];
        }
        mergeSort(left, low, mid);
        mergeSort(right, mid + 1, high);
        merge(left, right);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

private void merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
    int lLength = left.length;
    int rLength = right.length;
    // Pointer for left array
    int i = 0;
    // Pointer for right array
    int j = 0;
    // Pointer for merged array
    int k = 0;
    while (i < lLength && j < rLength) {
        if (left[i] < right[j]) {
            arrayToSort[k] = left[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arrayToSort[k] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i < lLength) {
        arrayToSort[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < rLength) {
        arrayToSort[k] = right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help!

edit: Noticed a mistake in my code (a parameter wasn't getting used) and modified it. Here is the error I get now (from the above code):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at Launcher.mergeSort(Launcher.java:43)
at Launcher.mergeSort(Launcher.java:49)
at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:21)
```

So it complains at the line

```
left[i - low] = array[i];
```

Comment: merge() looks correct, except it isn't really clear where arrayToSort comes from. I take it that it's a class var?

Comment: That doesn't compile, so your debugger can't show you anything.

Comment: Why does `mergeSort()` have a parameter called `array` when you don't use it, and where is `arrayToSort` defined (both methods)? *Hint: Both are the cause of your problem.*

Comment: @grill yeah it is, sorry

Comment: Nope. When you call `mergeSort()`, it's supposed to sort the `array` parameter, right? How does that work when `merge()` doesn't know the array? Start by removing `arrayToSort` as a field, and change both methods to **`static`**. Now make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you spot the problem in this snippet? ->

```
int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
int[] left = new int[mid];
int[] right = new int[high - mid];
// ...
mergeSort(left, low, mid);
mergeSort(right, mid + 1, high);
```

What about the size of `left` and `right`, and the indexes passed to the recursive call to `mergeSort`?

The indexes you pass, are indexes in the received array, not in `left` and `right`.
The problem is most obvious when you look at `right`. The index `high` will be inevitably always out of bounds.
The above would make more sense like this:

```
mergeSort(left, 0, left.length);
mergeSort(right, 0, high.length);
```

Now the indexes are correct. They are also pointless, because now they are simply the full range of the sub-arrays, and as such not needed at all. This weirdness is just a symptom of a deeper problem.

Keep in mind that `merge` must eventually update the original array. For that it needs the reference to the original array, and the left and right *ranges*. You are passing to merge the left and right *sub-arrays*. The reference to the original array and the indexes of the ranges are lost in your implementation.

Consider this:

```
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    mergeSort(array, low, mid);
    mergeSort(array, mid + 1, high);
    merge(array, low, mid, high);
```

Notice that:

- the original array reference is preserved, as it's passed down to recursive calls
- the indexes are valid indexes in the original array
- there are no more sub-arrays here

Change your implementation of `merge` accordingly, to merge the specified ranges in the array, modifying that array. An easy way to do it is to merge the ranges into a work array of size high - low, and then copying from the merged work array back to the range in the original.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code, the second recursive call should be:

```
    mergeSort(right, mid, high);
```

More space than is needed is allocated for left:

```
    int[] left = new int[mid-low];
```

Merge() function needs a low parameter to know where to start the merge at (k = low, not k = 0).

I wonder why bottom up merge sort is rarely taught these days, as it's simpler to understand.